# React.useContext and Minified React error #321;

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context

I have a context:

```
export const AppConstArrays = createContext({
    neededHours: [],
    setNeededHours: (neededHours: INeededHours[]) => { },
    serviceTypes: [],
    setServiceserviceTypes: (serviceTypes:IServiceTypes[]) => { },
});
```

I am able to use the set functions in a data service this works with no error.

```
ArraysState.setNeededHours(neededHours);
ArraysState.setServiceserviceTypes(services);
```

When I try to use it elsewhere,

```
export default function reCalc(index:number) {  //This is not a function component?
    const ArraysState = React.useContext(AppConstArrays);

}
```

The tslinter is OK but at run time, I get the nasty 321 :-)

```
sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_8439e1230cb8ca442df6f89cf19f89a6.js:1 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321
Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
```

truth be told, I do not have a provider anywhere for it because I use it in a .ts file
Any help?
Thank yeAll

Answer (score 0):

As it states [in the link](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321) in the error message:

> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Here it means that you can't call `React.useContext` outside of a function component.

You should not use values in a React Context anywhere outside of React components. If you need to do so, you can simply pass them as input arguments from your components to those functions (say `reCalc`).

For example if you want to call `setNeededHours` in an API caller function, it can be like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const { setNeededHours } = React.useContext(AppConstArrays)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchSomething({ /* input data */ }, setNeededHours)
  }, [])

  return <div>Some Content</div>
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but no. I have another context that works fine in same functions. I will try to move the value to the context that works and see. In any way thank you for answering

Comment: Anytime. Yes, it may work (depending on where/how it is called) but it's really fragile and can introduce unexpected issues likes this. It's better to follow the standard practices to avoid such problems.